# iOS take a screen snapshot only of background view

Tags: uiview, ios7, uiimage

I have a UIView (background) that contains another UIView (custom UI element).

Pressing a button will slide the top most view up to display more options.

I want to take a snapshot of everything on the screen with the exception of the top most view and the items it contains. This will be used to give the iOS7 blurred effect, but the UI that is animating is also put in the screenshot which obviously ruins the effect.

Here is my code that takes a snap shot of the whole screen (including the top most view).

Current Code:

```
-(UIImage *)blurredSnapshot
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);

    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    // Get the snapshot
    UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // Now apply the blur effect using Apple's UIImageEffect category
    UIImage *blurredSnapshotImage = [snapshotImage applyLightEffect];

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return blurredSnapshotImage;

}
```

Is this even possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could take the snapshot before animating the top view.
There are some public libraries like [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView) on GitHub and CocoaControls. You should check them.

Comment: This is actually what I am already doing. The problem is the top view is already half showing at ALL TIMES. There is a technical reason for this that I won't get into, but because it's already showing, the screen shot includes it.

Comment: I don't know if this will end up visually, but you could hide the top view, setup the blur view and unhide the top view back. I'm not sure if the view will flick of will be imperceptible.

Comment: Another idea is, if the background is somewhat static, you could edit your library to always used a pre-saved image, which does not contain the topview.